# TextBox.Lines property, signature is read write but I get read only and no helpful errors

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, c++-cli

In my quest to smoothly update `TextBox` characters programmatically, I happened upon the TextBox.Lines property. From its signature

```
[LocalizableAttribute(true)] 
public:
property array<String^>^ Lines {
    array<String^>^ get ();
    void set (array<String^>^ value);
}
```

it appears to offer read-write access, however when I update a single line I don't see the update apply within the debugger nor on-screen. Why does MicroSoft publish misleading headers when it could simply omit the set accessor from the property declaration?

The MSDN entry http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=VS.80%29.aspx offers some confusing advice:

> NoteNote
>
> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines in the TextBox. To get a writable collection of lines, use code similar to the following: `textBox1.Lines = new string[] { "abcd" }`;

But that is not getting any lines at all but instead is setting them. Does that code snippet have further significance in allowing individual lines to be updated? If so, what am I missing?
**EDIT**
Jon, here's how I thought I had updated it

```
for ( int counter = 0; counter < lineStrideInBytes - NEWLINECHARCNT; counter++ )
{
    int srcI = LineBeingWrittenI * (lineStrideInBytes) + counter;
    replacedLine->Append(TextBoxStr[srcI]);
}
replacedLine->AppendLine(); //NEWLINECHARS
replacedLine[col] = chr; //Updated char
textBox1->Lines[LineBeingWrittenI] = replacedLine->ToString();
```

Comment: How did you try to apply an update? I don't see what's misleading here - it's always worked fine for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically when you read the property, it will make a copy. If you change the returned array, that won't do anything *in itself* but you can always set the value back. For example (C#):

```
string[] lines = textBox.Lines;
lines[5] = "Updated!";
textBox.Lines = lines;
```

The important thing here is that you're *writing* to the property. Remember that a property is just a getter/setter pair; it's calling the *setter* that changes the lines in the text box.

Comment: Wow, that's almost an exact reduplication of the Text property then! I'm gonna have to look at co-operating better with the Windows messages and handled flag in that case.

Comment: @John: Except that it's done the text splitting for you, quite possibly more efficiently than you could do otherwise in managed code.

Comment: Not only does changing the returned array, or element of, not update, (copy by value), but assigning to individual elements does not update those either. On closer inspection the signature is for whole array assignment and not misleading, but underpowered for C++ enthusiasts.

Comment: @John: The signature makes perfect sense from a C# perspective, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was just kiding because it's Jon Skeet's answer with too few upvotes... don't me wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way; look more closely at the signature... what is that property? an array of strings. That *array* is read/write.

But as Jon notes, when you read it, you are getting a copy of it, so setting one line as you are doing basically has no effect. You need to set the whole array, after altering the copy.